# Slipstreamed WS2016 updates

Tags: powershell, windows-update, windows-server, windows-server-2016, slipstream

Hope this is the right forum for it so here I go.

I've made a script that automates ISO Slipstreaming for Windows Server 2016, but I have found a problem that I can't seem to solve, after I succesfully inserted the updates into the ISO and install the ISO on a virtual machine, and then I check in my installed update list and I see Cumulative KB4489889 and after that I decide to 'Check for updates' and it finds the same cumulative update KB4489889 and says it's downloading it, but it should already be installed.

Is this normal when slipstreaming, or how can I solve it? If you're interested in the code, I will send you a paste-bin link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `winver` to determine what build you have installed and update your question with that vital information.

Comment: It is 1607 so it should be the latest version, since 1709 and 1803 are core installations.

Comment: Please use `winver` and provided the specific build number you are on currently.  1607 is not specific enough, without the information, I am asking for, your question cannot be answered.  I am not interested about anything with regards to`1709` or `1803`

Comment: OS Build 14393.2879

Comment: `KB4489889` is 14393.2879 so I suspect your problem is simply that your Windows Update cache is outdated or corrupt.  Have you tried to reset Windows Update to see if the update will stop being offered?  You obviously cannot install an update twice.  I also assume you have tried to reboot?  Instead of submitting a comment please provide all relevant information in the question body.